# rosbridge for melodic distro?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosbridge, rosbridge-suite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently trying to get rosbridge to run on an Ubuntu-VM. I installed ROS with no problems, but when I try to install rosbridge (which should be "sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-rosbridge-suite") it tells me, that he is unable to locate the package.

I haven't found any source online for what distros of ROS Rosbridge is available, so can someone help me out here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292619/rosbridge-for-melodic-distro?/) by [Funny](https://answers.ros.org/users/35550/funny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-05-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-30**:\

> I haven't found any source online for what distros of ROS Rosbridge is available

In addition to the pages that @130s linked to, you can always go to the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) of a package and check the version selectors at the top of the page.

**Comment by [Funny](https://answers.ros.org/users/35550/funny/) on 2018-05-30**:
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any `rosbridge` packages don't seem to be released yet at the moment (see [repositories.ros.org](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=rosbridge)). Some of its dependent package isn't released yet either (see [another page on repositories.ros.org](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/blocked_releases_melodic.html?q=rosbridge&s=6&r=1)), which means it'll become release-able once dependent packages are released.

Looks like there's already [a request](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/issues/333). Voicing up there is the best way to communicate with the maintenance team of the package in question.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2